# How to bind ant to a maven-plugin custom goal

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

The way to integrate maven with ant is to simply use the maven-antrun-plugin like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>package</id>                        
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>             
        <ant antfile="build.xml" target="package" />
      </tasks>
    </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

in your project's pom.xml file

However I want to be able to have that associated build.xml script along with the execution configuration as part of a maven plugin that defines a custom packaging and a lifecycle.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an experiment that did this a little while ago.  Have a look at the [maven-plugin-in-ant](https://github.com/happygiraffe/jslint4java/tree/maven-plugin-in-ant) branch of jslint4java.